# Retrieve value for Temporary column based on the value of a column in sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Query as below :

```
SELECT SUM(Z.MaxMarks) AS TotMaxMarks,
    SUM(Z.MinMarks) AS TotMinMarks,
    SUM(Z.SecuredMarks) AS TotSecuredMarks,
    Z.IsPass
FROM (
    SELECT Y.*
    FROM (
        SELECT X.MaxMarks,
            X.SecuredMarks,
            (X.MaxMarks * X.PassPercentage / 100) AS MinMarks,
            CASE WHEN ((X.MaxMarks * X.PassPercentage / 100) < X.SecuredMarks) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS IsPass,
            row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY ChapterID ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC
                ) AS SequencNo
        FROM (
            SELECT C.ChapterID,
                T.MinimumMarks AS PassPercentage,
                (
                    SELECT Sum(Q.MaximumMarks)
                    FROM MstQuestion Q,
                        TransStudentAnswer SA
                    WHERE Q.QuestionID = SA.QuestionID AND SA.TestAllotmentID = TA.TestAllotmentID
                    ) AS MaxMarks,
                (
                    SELECT Sum(Score)
                    FROM TransStudentAnswer
                    WHERE TestAllotmentID = TA.TestAllotmentID
                    ) AS SecuredMarks,
                TA.UpdatedDate
            FROM TransTestAllotment TA,
                MstStudent S,
                MstBatchDetails B,
                MstTest T,
                MstChapter C
            WHERE TA.StudentID = 47 AND TA.BatchID = 10 AND T.TestID = TA.TestID AND S.StudentID = TA.StudentID AND B.BatchID = TA.BatchID AND T.ChapterID = C.ChapterID AND TA.IsAttempted = 'True' AND TA.IsEvaluated = 'True'
            ) X
        ) Y
    WHERE SequencNo = 1
    ) Z
GROUP BY Z.IsPass
```

It is returning results as below :

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+
| TotMaxMarks | TotMinMarks | TotSecuredMarks | IsPass |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+
|          20 |          10 |               3 | False  |
|          30 |          15 |              28 | True   |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+
```

Is it possible to modify this query such that it returns one record with `SUM(Z.MaxMarks),SUM(Z.MinMarks),SUM(Z.SecuredMarks) and TempIsPass column` whose value will be `true` if value of the column `Z.Ispass is true` in all records of Z, else it should be false.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

Select the table you get into a temporary table 'z' using SELECT INTO query. Then do this

```
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(IsPass) FROM Z);
    SET @count1 = (SELECT COUNT(IsPass) FROM Z WHERE IsPass='true');

    IF(@count = @count1)
    THEN
        SELECT SUM(Z.MaxMarks) AS MaxMarks, SUM(Z.MinMarks) AS MinMarks, SUM(Z.SecuredMarks) AS SecuredMarks, 'true' AS TempIsPass FROM Z
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In your select clause, replace `Z.IsPass` with:

```
case when min(case when Z.IsPass = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end
```